# Python- Can't get to print you win

Tags: python

Can't seem to get it to print "congratulations, you are correct" after getting the guess correct.

from random import randint

guessesTaken = 0

randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)] # create list of random nums

while guessesTaken < 10:

```
guesses = list(input("Guess Number: ")) # create list of four digits
check = "".join([b if a==b else "H" if int(a)>int(b) else "L" for a, b in zip(guesses,randomNumber)])
if all(c == 'Y' for c in check):  # if check has four Y's we have a correct guess
    print("Congratulations, you are correct, it took you", guessesTaken, "guesses.")
    break
else:
    guessesTaken += 1 # else increment guess count and ask again
    print(check)
if guessesTaken == 10:
    print("You lose")
```

Comment: `check == randomNumber` **does not** test *"if check has four Y's"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is because `check` is a string and `randomNumber` is a list, comparing them will always return `False`. You need to change the type of one of them to compare it in the way that you want to. Change the `if` statement to this:

```
if check == ''.join(randomNumber):
```